# How to split the string into different kafka topic based on some conditions

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to split the string into different kafka topic based on conditions.
Here is the topology.

1. Split the string into words.
2. Match every words with conditions (here set of Good words and set of Bad words)
3. If atleast 1 words from Bad words set found in the string, it will be sent to Bad-string
   topic otherwise it will be sent to Good-string topic.

Problem:

> Every string is going to only one topic. (Bad-string topic)

Input:

> 1. Your service was good.
> 2. He was angry and sad.
> 3. Your service was bad but still I am happy.

Output:
**good-string (topic)**

> Your service was good. ( It contains Good words, "good" )

**bad-string (topic)**

> 1. He was angry and sad ( It contains Bad words, "angry" and "sad" )
> 2. Your service was bad but still I am happy.        (Though, there is a
>    Good word "happy" but there is atleast one         Bad word "bad" )

Here is the code:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class SplitSentence {
    
    private static final Set<String> BAD_WORDS = Set.of("angry", "sad", "bad");
    private static final Set<String> GOOD_WORDS = Set.of("happy", "good", "helpful");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    public KStream<String,String> windowCount(StreamsBuilder builder)
    {
        var stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        var jsonSerde = new JsonSerde<>(CountingDemo.class);

        ((JsonDeserializer) jsonSerde.deserializer()).setUseTypeHeaders(false);

        var input = builder.stream("counting",Consumed.with(stringSerde,jsonSerde));

        var feedbackStreams = input.flatMap(splitWords()).branch(isGoodWord(), isBadWord());
        
        boolean newString = feedbackStreams[1].toString().isEmpty();

        if(newString)
            input.to("good-string");
        else    
            input.to("bad-string");

        return input;
    }

    private Predicate<? super String, ? super String> isBadWord() {
        return (key, value) -> BAD_WORDS.contains(value);
    }

    private Predicate<? super String, ? super String> isGoodWord() {
        return (key, value) -> GOOD_WORDS.contains(value);
    }

    private KeyValueMapper<String, CountingDemo, Iterable<KeyValue<String,String>>> splitWords() 
    {
        return (key,value) -> Arrays
                            .asList(value.getText().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s+")).stream()
                            .distinct().map(word -> KeyValue.pair(value.getText(), word)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

CountingDemo.java

```
public class CountingDemo {
    
    private String name;
    private String text;
}
```

Where am I wrong ?
Is there any better logic for this ?

Comment: 1) What did you expect `feedbackStreams[1].toString()` to do? This is never empty. 2) How about you write some unit tests for this rather than in your main app logic?

Comment: @OneCricketeer `feedbackStream[1]` will contains bad words from the original string. So I am converting it to string and then checking whether it is empty or not.  If it is empty means it does not have any bad words means original string is a good-string. Then it must go to good-string topic. But if `feedbackStream` contains at least 1 word , it means original string has atleast 1 bad word then original string must go to bad-string topic.

Comment: Actually `feedbackStream[1]` will not "contain words" at all since this is just metadata of a topology, not a representation of a collection. That being said, you're still running `isEmpty` on a string of an object, not a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement is always false because the `.toString()` of a KStream object is the metadata of it, and never empty.

And if you want the full original string split between the two topics, you should not flatmap at all.

That being said, seems like you want

```
var feedbackStreams = input.branch(hasGoodWords(), hasBadWords());

feedbackStreams[0].to("good-string");
feedbackStreams[1].to("bad-string");
```

Where the two functions get the full input message and compare against the sets, rather than be given individual words.
Although, I think you only need **one** function to capture *all messages with a good word* to `good-string`, and *all other messages* (no good/bad, both good/bad, and some bad) to the `bad-string` topic

e.g.

```
    var feedbackStreams = input.branch(this::hasOnlyGoodWords, (k,v) -> true);
    feedbackStreams[0].to("good-string");
    feedbackStreams[1].to("bad-string");
    return input;
}

private boolean hasOnlyGoodWords(Object key, String value) {
    String cleaned = value.getText().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase();
    Set<String> uniqueWords = Arrays.stream(cleaned.split("\\s+")).distinct().collect(toSet());
    for (String s : BAD_WORDS) {
        if (uniqueWords.contains(s)) return false;
    }
    uniqueWords.retainAll(GOOD_WORDS);
    return uniqueWords.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: `feedbackStreems`   contains words like `Your`, `service`, `was`, `good`  and then then it gets compared with GOOD_WORDS and BAD_WORDS and then `feedbackStream[0]` will have words from GOOD_WORDS and `feedbackStream[1]` will have words from BAD_WORDS.  But I dont want this, I want whole string to be go to one of the topic based on the words it contains. Please check input and expected output of the propgram. I have just updated.

Comment: Don't use splitwords before the branch so the whole string will be checked in the condition , inside the condition isGood isBad you can split to words ...

Comment: @OneCricketeer I understood your approach. But there require little bit modification. Because above approach is saying if there is atleast one GOOD_WORDS then string must go to good-string topic. I want it if there is atleast 1 BAD_WORDS then string must go in bad-string topic.  I corrected it and now perfectly working. Thank you.

Comment: @RanLupovich I did what you saying like  `var feedbackStreams = input.branch(isGoodWord(), isBadWord());feedbackStreams[0].to("good-string");
         feedbackStreams[1].to("bad-string");`  But  string is not appearing in any topic.

Comment: Post an update of your isGood / isBad functions

Comment: Keeping your line of thought, create hasGood which split to words and calls isGood for each word in the string, if any good words found on string return true ... notice you might have bad and good in same string ... according to your business requirement doCheck for badwords if no badwords found send to good.. but thats pure java string manipulation not streams related question,  maybe post new question

Comment: @OneCricketeer might I suggest change the function name to "doesntHaveBadWords" / fix the calling in the branch to the correct function name

Comment: @RanLupovich Thanks. Forgot to update the function ref.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, your code is working.  I was bit busy so could not visit. Thank you.